# Converting subtitles for different framerates

Tags: algorithm, video, subtitle

I'm trying to make a simple CLI program that parses a SRT subtitle file and creates a new one, editing the timestamps to fit the desired framerate.
Eg I have a one-hour video track that runs at 25.0fps, with proper subtitles.
When encoding the same video at 23.976fps, the output video is a few seconds shorter (3 seconds approximately)

I've tried applying the following cross product to each time value in my srt file :

```
timestamp = timestamp * outputfps / inputfps
```

This produces captions that are approx. 3 minutes earlier compared to the input SRT (for the last captions - for the first ones the delay is obviously lesser), where the maximum delay should be 3 seconds, according to the new video file length.

This is all new for me and it seems obvious that something's wrong with the way I convert these timestamps. Could you please highlight my mistake?

**Edit** : According to j_random_hacker clever answer, the video should have the same duration at 25 than at 12 fps, which is easily verified. Seems like the 3 seconds offset I have is there no matter what the output framerate is - I guess there's some sort of trimming happening back there.

The main question remains : how does one convert a subtitle track so it doesn't go out of sync as the video file plays? (see my own comment below if this is unclear)

Comment: Depending on the programming language you use in your CLI it may simply be a problem of arithmetic precision. You can test this by encoding a video with exactly the half fps and test if the error still occurs.

Comment: I may be missing something, but AFAICT, the timestamps specify the absolute moments in time you want to start and stop displaying the subtitles, right?  If so then the right thing to do is *not change* the timestamps at all.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's also what I'm starting to realize.
But then, what's the concrete difference between the same subtitles with different framerates? SRT framerate is often specified on subtitles websites (thinking of opensubtitles or isubtitles), and using one that's not fitting the video's framerate results in subs becoming more and more out of sync as the playing goes.

Comment: Good question, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that...  And I've spent more time than any human should getting furious with VLC for speeding up/slowing down/just plain dropping subtitles :-|

Comment: From you explanation, I'm guessing that the conversion involves skipping every 25th frame (or every 12.5th interlaced half-frame) to get to 24 fps, and then slowing down slightly to 23.976 fps. This would indeed create a file that is 3.6 seconds longer for every hour. So your ratio should not be `25 / 23.976` but `24 / 23.976`, or `1000 / 999`.

Comment: I think your encoding is wrong. If you have 1 hour at 25fps, that is 3600*25 = 90000 frames. If you playback these frames at 23.976 fps, the video should be 3753.7... seconds: 154 seconds longer. Your encoding is not rewrapping existing frames into a container saying to play them at 23.976 fps, but is dropping frames instead to try to maintain the timings. And it does seems to not do it precisely, resulting in your 3 seconds offset in duration.